# Selective deletion of files in folder according to the name

Tags: c#

I would like to know (using c#) how I can delete files in a certain directory whose name contains *mhz.prj.

In fact there are several files in this folder and I want to delete only Amhz.prj Bmhz.prj for example. My problem is that the end of the filename is important.

Comment: Have you looked into `File.Delete()`? if not, it sure is the time to do so!

Comment: Actually I couldn't find solutions because I didn't know the word wildcard ..
In fact the problem is the selection ?
`string[] List = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*mhz.prj");` will work ?

Comment: First hit on Google for File.Delete() is MSDN's full example that presents a solution to your problem... searching for an answer might sometime be faster than posting a question on SO and waiting for an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through `C:\MyDir` and delete any files with the extension `prj`.

```
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyDir", "*.prj"))
{
    File.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(file));
}
```